# Using CombineFileInputFormat in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to write a Map Reduce program for which I have around 1000 small files (of size in few MBs each) as input. From what I understand, this will result in around 1000 mapper tasks being created (HDFS block size is default 64MB). So, using CombineFileInputFormat will be more efficient than the TextInputFormat in this case. Am I correct?

If so, how to use CombineFileInputFormat in my program?

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop api not provide a fully concrete implementation for `CombineFileInputFormat` yet.
I myself implemented  somewhat. Have a look at : https://github.com/thomachan/Custom-MR/tree/master/src/mapreduce/hi/api/input/defaultcustom